# Parsing and inserting bulk data. How to keep performance and do relations?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, csv

**The data**

I have a collection with around 300,000 vacations. Every vacation has several categories, countries, cities, activities and other subobjects. This data needs to be inserted into a MySQL / SQL Server database. I have the luxury of being able to truncate the entire database and start clean every time the parser program is run.

**What I have tried**

I have tried working with Entity Framework, this is also where my preference lies. To keep Entity Framework's performance up I have created a construction where 300 items are taken out of the vacations collection, parsed and inserted by Entity Framework and it's context disposed thereafter. The program finishes in a matter of minutes using this method. If I fill the context with all 300k vacations from the collection (and it's subobjects) it's a matter of hours.

```
int total = vacationsObjects.Count;          

for (int i = 0; i < total; i += Math.Min(300, (total - i)))
{
  var set = vacationsObjects.Skip(i).Take(300);
  int enumerator = 0;

  using (var database = InitializeContext())
  {
   foreach (VacationModel vacationData in set)
   {
      enumerator++;;

      Vacations vacation = new Vacations
      {
         ProductId = vacationData.ExternalId,
         Name = vacationData.Name,
         Description = vacationData.Description,
         Price = vacationData.Price,
         Url = vacationData.Url,
      };

      foreach (string category in vacationData.Categories)
      {
         var existingCategory = database.Categories.Local.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CategoryName == categor);

         if (existingCategory != null)
            vacation.Categories.Add(existingCategory);
         else
         {
            vacation.Categories.Add(new Category
            {
              CategoryName = category
            });
         }
      }

      database.Vacations.Add(vacation);
   }

   database.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

The downside (and possibly dealbreaker) with this method is figuring out the relationships. As you can see when adding a Category I check if it's already been created in the local context, and then use that. But what if it has been added in a previous set of 300? I don't want to query the database multiple times for every vacation to check whether an entity already resides within it.

**Possible solution**

I could keep a dictionary in memory containing the categories that have been added. I'd need to figure out how to attach these categories to the proper vacations (or vice-versa) and insert them, including their respective relations into the database.

**Possible alternatives**

*Segregate the context and the transaction* -

Purely theoretical, I do not know if I'm making any sense here. Maybe I could have EF's context keep track of all objects, and take manual control over the inserting part. I have messed around with this, trying to work with manual transaction scopes without avail.

*Stored procedure* -

I could write a stored procedure that handles and inserts my data. I'm not a big fan of this alternative, as I would like to keep the flexibility of switching between MySQL and SQL Server. Also, I would be in the dark as to where to begin.

*Intermediary CSV file* -

Instead of inserting parsed data directly into the RDMBS, I could export it into one or more CSV files and make use of importing tools such as MySQL's INFLINE.

*Alternative database systems*

Databases such as Azure Table Storage, MongoDB or RavenDB could be an option. However, I would prefer to stick to a traditional RDMBS due to compatibility with my skillset and tools.

I have been working on and researching this problem for a couple of weeks now. It seems like the best way of finding a solution that fits is by simply trying the different possibilities and observing the result.  I was hoping that I could receive some pointers or tips from your personal experiences.

Comment: I just can give you my point of view from MSSQL side, because i wasn’t work on ETL task with MySQL since two years. 
The bulk load functions in MSSQL are very performant. I load every day many millions of rows. With a SPOC bulk insert orwith SSIS (which I would recommend for inserting data) you can do the Job easily. 
If you can truncate your stage table daily, you can insert the data without normalization. 
In a second step you can normalize your attributes like category or city. In a last step, when finished to update your dimension tables, you can process the staged data into a fact table.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert each record separately, the whole operation will take a lot of time. The bottleneck is SQL-queries between client and server. Each query takes time, so try to avoid using multiple of them. For huge amount of data it will be much better to process them locally. The best solution is to use special import tool. In MySQL you can use [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/loading-tables.html), in MSSQL there is [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx). To import your data, you need a `.css` file.

To handle external keys correctly, you must populate tables manually before inserting. If destination tables are empty, you can simply create `.css` file with predefined primary and external keys. Otherwise you can import existing records from server, update them with your data, then export them back.

Comment: I can keep the amount of queries on an acceptible level if I save & dispose the context every 300 objects or so. Ofcourse, this is only viable if I find a way to handle my relations programaticially.

I will look into LOAD DATA and BULK INSERT. Do you know of any clear advatages it has over the similar method I found - an intermidary CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

**Time**

Since you can afford to make only `INSERT`s, one suggestion is to try [Entity Framework Bulk Insert extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/). I have used it to save up to 200K records and it works fine. Just include in your project and write something like this:

```
context.BulkInsert(listOfEntities);
```

This should solve (or greatly improve the EF version) your problem's the time dimension

**Data integrity**

Keeping everything in one transaction does not sound reasonable (I expect that 300K parent records to generate at least 3M overall records), so I would try the following approach:

1) make your entities insertion using bulk insert.

2) call a stored procedure to check data integrity

If the insertion is quite long and the chance of failure is relatively big, you can load what is already loaded and have the process skip what is already loaded:

1) make smaller bulk inserts for a batch of vacation records and all its children records. Ensure that it runs in a transaction. One BULK INSERT is run atomically (no transaction needed), for several [it seems tricky](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk(v=vs.110).aspx).

2) if the process fails, you have complete vacation data in your database (no partially imported vacation)

3) retake the process, but load existing vacation records (parents only). Using EF, a faster way is using [AsNoTracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) to spare the tracking overhead (which is great for large lists)

```
var existingVacations = context.Vacation.Select(v => v.VacationSourceIdentifier).AsNoTracking();
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Alexei, EntityFramework.BulkInsert is a very good solution if your model is supported by this library.

You can also use [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) (PRO Version) which allow to use BulkSaveChanges and Bulk Operations (Insert, Update, Delete and Merge).

It's support your both provider: MySQL and SQL Server

```
// Upgrade SaveChanges performance with BulkSaveChanges
var context = new CustomerContext();
// ... context code ...

// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(operation => operation.BatchSize = 1000);

// Use direct bulk operation
context.BulkInsert(customers);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)